# Why Windows is not picking up the 128 pixels icons from my exe file?

Tags: windows

I created and exe file in which I added 32, 48, 64 and 128 pixels icons. 
When I put the exe on my desktop or navigate to the folder where the exe is stored, Windows Explorer shows only the 32 and 48 pixels icons. If I set my desktop to show 'Large icons' it still shows the 48 pix icon. Why?

---

Windows 7 32 bit, RBG+Alpha icons, EXE built with Delphi 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you making your .ico file ? I think generally you need to start with adding the highest resolution first, and work down from there. You could troubleshoot by starting with only the 128x128 one, seeing if that works, then adding the 64x64 one and so on.

An easy alternative way is to try generating the .ico file using http://iconverticons.com/ instead, it's free and pretty painless.

Comment: I have tried both ways - 128 pixel first then deleted all and put 32 pixel first. No luck. I have tried that EVEN if my resource file editor allows me to change the order of the icons. Anyway your idea with 128 pixels only is good! Thanks.